# Nginx ssl with included files

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have the following config which is working

my `nginx.conf`

```
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {}

http {
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name host.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/host.access.log;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/host.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/host.com.key;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://other-host.com/;
        }
    }
}
```

and I am trying do do something like that

My `nginx.conf`

```
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {}

http {
    include front/*
}
```

My `front/host.com.conf`

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name host.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/host.access.log;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/host.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/host.com.key;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://other-host.com/;
        }
    }
```

In this case I have an error 525, I don't understand why, the configuration should be exactly the same

Comment: Please expand on the exact error as `error 525` doesn't really mean much on its own. The only common 525 error I'm aware of is a Cloudflare one, but you do not mention Cloudflare in your post. Providing precise information is more likely to get a better response.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that is just copy-paste error, but your config should not work because of forgotten ';' after include.

```
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {}

http {
    include front/*;
}
```